# send C-< and M-! in emacs within tmux

Tags: emacs, tmux, xterm

I can send `C-<` in emacs in xterm, but do not work within tmux.

`M-!` do not work in both situations.

`C-<` is used in outline-promote
`M-!` is used in shell-command

ps: I know Esc can do the shell-command function.

Comment: Terminals (such as tmux or xterm) often don't send all key presses.  For instance, in urxvt, `C-<` is aliased to `<`.  If you do `C-h k C-<`, it should tell you what key was received; if it's not `C-<`, then the terminal isn't sending the keypress you want.  You need to somehow configure the terminal to send the correct keypress, use a different key, or use the GUI.

Comment: @jpkotta you are right. it is the emulators' issue.